# join 2 tables on hardcoded value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I don't understand quite how do  some parts of the 'join' work.

I have 2 tables that I need to join on some columns.

Lets say the following relations:

`TabA ( IDA, IDB, Label, isActive)`

`TabB (IDB, INFORMATION)`

Here we join them on `IDB`. But what if we want to join on`isActive = 1`?

What will happen?

```
Select * 
  from TabA
  left join TabB 
    on TabA.IDB = TabB.IDB 
    and isActive = 1
```

I get some kind of cartesian product but I don't understand why nor what logic?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query.  What is it about the results that you don't understand?

Comment: `isactive = 1` is a filter for TABA's rows, it's not a join predicate so you join all rows from TABB to each row from that filtered TABA

Comment: I was incorrect a little in my previous comment: rows from `TABA` wouldn't filtered but recordset would have NULL value in TabB's columns for such rows (which don't meet the condition `isactive = 1`)

Comment: Find a definition of left join and tell us what you think should happen & why & ask a question where you are stuck. Otherwise you are just asking, how does left join work, and that's an easily found multiply duplicate question.

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join.

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. PS But what if we want to join on Tuesday?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 0):

you can join two table where they have a common field like here you have IDB but isactive is not belong on the both table

you can use isactive in where clause:

```
Select TabA.* from TabA
left join TabB 
on TabA.IDB = TabB.IDB 
where TabA.isactive = 1
```

Comment: . . This answer is simply wrong and you should understand why.

Answer (score 0):

This query is an outer join:

```
Select *
from TabA a left join
     TabB b
     on a.IDB = b.IDB and b.isactive = 1;
```

This follows the same rules of any `left join`.  *All* the rows in `TabA` are in the result set.  In addition, any matches from `TabB` are included.  In this case, only rows from `TabB` where `isactive = 1` are included.  If there is no row, then all matching columns are NULL.

For instance, if you have `tabA` as:

```
IDA     IDB
 1       1
 2       1
 3       2
```

And `tabB` as:

```
IDB    isactive
 1         0
 2         1
```

Then the result set is:

```
IDA     IDB    IDB    isActive
 1       1     NULL      NULL
 2       1     NULL      NULL
 3       2      2        1
```

Comment: `isActive` is a column of `TabA`